# delete column in sql but previous data can not be deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i want to delete column in sql but data in that deleted column should not be deleted it should remains as previous. when i execute the table it should show all column name except deleted column and when i search the data from that table it should show previously deleted column data and new column data..
is there any option in sql for these kind of situation..
thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide a column from some people? If you delete a column.... its gone. You could also create a view over the table that doesn't have that column

Comment: If you want to hide the column from some people, use column security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about soft deletion or logical deletion. In such case the best idea is to have one Boolean column `is_deleted` or something like that. Whenever you delete the record mark `is_deleted=TRUE` , by default is_deleted will be `FALSE`